# Determinant bundle of torsion free sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $\nu\colon X^\nu\to X$ be normalization of a nodal curve, $L$ be a line bundle on $X$, $\nu_*L$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, but we can take its determinant bundle, by taking alternating tensor product of a free resolution. Suppose $X$ is the nodal cubic, what is the determinant line bundle of $v_*\mathcal{O}_{X^\nu}(P)$? For $P$ lies in one of inverse image of the nodes?

Is this determinant construction of taking better understood as quotient or sub of the $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{X^\nu}$?

Comment: How do you take the alternating tensor product of a free resolution, if the resolution is infinite, which is the case for your coherent sheaf?

Comment: @Mohan Yes you are right...sorry I didn't realize the question doesn't make sense in this case. (The original question I had in mind was this... looks quite distant.. suppose $X$ is an abelian variety, $i\colon Y\to X$ be a sub-abelian variety, do we know explicitly what is the determinant bundle of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$?)

Comment: I think this is trivial if $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$ is if $Y$ is a divisor and $\mathcal{O}_X$ if $Y$ has higher codimension, as such determinant bundle contruction commutes with open immersion. Is this correct?

Comment: You are right in both cases.

Comment: @Mohan Do we know the case when $\pi\colon X\to Y$ is a surjection of abelian varieties, and $L$ is some line bundle in $\mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$, then what will be the determinant line bundle of the coherent sheaf $\pi_*L$

Comment: What information do you want to put in? For a simple example, take a line bundle $L$ with order of $L=n$. Then consider the corresponding cover given by spectrum $X$ of $\oplus_{i=0}^{n-1} L^i$, which is an abelian variety. Take $\pi:X\to Y$ be the obvious map and then determinant of $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is  $L^{n(n-1)/2}$. Things can be much more complicated in general.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks! The case I am interested in is the following: Given a morphism of curves $f\colon X\to Y$ over $k=\overline{k}$, we have the map $f_*\colon \mathrm{Pic}_{X}\to\mathrm{Pic}_{Y}$, and thus a morphism $\phi\colon X\times\mathrm{Pic}_{X}\to Y\times\mathrm{Pic}_Y$. Take a universal line bundle $L$ on $X\times\mathrm{Pic}_X$ trivialized along a point $x\in X$, what would be the determinant bundle(or the determinant of cohomology? Are they the same?) of coherent sheaf $\phi_*L$ on $Y\times\mathrm{Pic}_Y$? Do we get the corresponding universal line bundle?